# Detect if another process is started as “Run as Administrator” for Visual Basic

Tags: c#, vb.net, admin, dllimport, elevated-privileges

I am asking the same question as this post "[Detect if another process is started as “Run as Administrator”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479551/detect-if-another-process-is-started-as-run-as-administrator)"

I tried converting the code to Visual Basic myself, but I am getting a lot of errors. As far as code, this is what I have so far:

```
    Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Security.Principal
Imports System.Reflection

Namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
    Public Class ProcessHelper
        <DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
        Private Shared Function OpenProcessToken(ByVal ProcessHandle As IntPtr, ByVal DesiredAccess As UInt32, <Out> ByRef TokenHandle As IntPtr) As Boolean
        <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
        Private Shared Function CloseHandle(ByVal hObject As IntPtr) As Boolean
        Private Const STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED As Integer = &HF0000
        Private Const TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY As Integer = &H1
        Private Const TOKEN_DUPLICATE As Integer = &H2
        Private Const TOKEN_IMPERSONATE As Integer = &H4
        Private Const TOKEN_QUERY As Integer = &H8
        Private Const TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE As Integer = &H10
        Private Const TOKEN_ADJUST_GROUPS As Integer = &H40
        Private Const TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES As Integer = &H20
        Private Const TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID As Integer = &H100
        Private Const TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT As Integer = &H80
        Private Const TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS As Integer = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED Or TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY Or TOKEN_DUPLICATE Or TOKEN_IMPERSONATE Or TOKEN_QUERY Or TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE Or TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES Or TOKEN_ADJUST_GROUPS Or TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID Or TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT)

        Public Shared Function IsProcessOwnerAdmin(ByVal processName As String) As Boolean
            Dim proc As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName)(0)
            Dim ph As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
            OpenProcessToken(proc.Handle, TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, ph)
            Dim iden As WindowsIdentity = New WindowsIdentity(ph)
            Dim result As Boolean = False

            For Each role As IdentityReference In iden.Groups

                If role.IsValidTargetType(GetType(SecurityIdentifier)) Then
                    Dim sid As SecurityIdentifier = TryCast(role, SecurityIdentifier)

                    If sid.IsWellKnown(WellKnownSidType.AccountAdministratorSid) OrElse sid.IsWellKnown(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinAdministratorsSid) Then
                        result = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next

            CloseHandle(ph)
            Return result
        End Function
    End Class

    Module Program
        <STAThread>
        Private Sub Main()
            Dim isAdmin As Boolean = ProcessHelper.IsProcessOwnerAdmin("outlook")
        End Sub
    End Module
End Namespace
```

Any idea on what I may be doing wrong here? I am trying to check to see if other processes are administrative level or not. I did research to see if there were any other vb.net threads for this on here. Plus- I did some simple google searching and couldn't find anything that wasn't in C#.

Most of my errors have to do with the dll importing and the private functions following those.

Thanks you guys in advanced!

**^^^EDITTTTT 7:06 PM**
So I applied "RobertBaron"'s code and this is the error that I receive? Was unable to find any threads related to this error.

[Error relating to edittt 7:06 PM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1CmN.png)

**^^^EDITTTTT 7:15 PM**

Sorry, I was able to find the answer to my edit. I found the answer here: "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/misc/bc31529" and the functions now look like this.

```
 <DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
    Private Shared Function OpenProcessToken(ByVal ProcessHandle As IntPtr, ByVal DesiredAccess As Integer, ByRef TokenHandle As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function

    <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
    Public Shared Function CloseHandle(ByVal hObject As IntPtr) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
    End Function
```

Comment: You know there are automatic online code converters which can help you go from c# to VB with less problems?

Comment: Anyway if you've got errors and you expect us to help you with them, it would make sense to tell us what they are, then we don't have to guess...

Comment: In most cases you just want to just require admin privileges and to force users to grant you them you can use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-do-i-force-my-net-application-to-run-as-administrator

Comment: RobertBaron was able to provide the revised code. I did do the automatic code converters but they failed. I used RobertBaron's revised code and it was all good except for a minor error. Would you guys mind to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Sorry, I found the answer here "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/misc/bc31529"

Answer (score 0):

Here is the converted function.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Security.Principal

Module Module1

    Sub Main(args As String())
        Dim result As Boolean
        result = IsProcessOwnerAdmin("calc")
    End Sub

    <DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
    Private Function OpenProcessToken(ByVal ProcessHandle As IntPtr, ByVal DesiredAccess As Integer, ByRef TokenHandle As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function

    <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
    Public Function CloseHandle(ByVal hObject As IntPtr) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
    End Function

    Private Const STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED As Integer = 983040
    Private Const TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY As Integer = 1
    Private Const TOKEN_DUPLICATE As Integer = 2
    Private Const TOKEN_IMPERSONATE As Integer = 4
    Private Const TOKEN_QUERY As Integer = 8
    Private Const TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE As Integer = 16
    Private Const TOKEN_ADJUST_GROUPS As Integer = 64
    Private Const TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES As Integer = 32
    Private Const TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID As Integer = 256
    Private Const TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT As Integer = 128
    Private Const TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS As Integer = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED _
                Or (TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY _
                Or (TOKEN_DUPLICATE _
                Or (TOKEN_IMPERSONATE _
                Or (TOKEN_QUERY _
                Or (TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE _
                Or (TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES _
                Or (TOKEN_ADJUST_GROUPS _
                Or (TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID Or TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT)))))))))

    Public Function IsProcessOwnerAdmin(ByVal processName As String) As Boolean
        Dim proc As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName)(0)
        Dim ph As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
        OpenProcessToken(proc.Handle, TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, ph)
        Dim iden As WindowsIdentity = New WindowsIdentity(ph)
        Dim result As Boolean = False
        For Each role As IdentityReference In iden.Groups
            If role.IsValidTargetType(GetType(SecurityIdentifier)) Then
                Dim sid As SecurityIdentifier = CType(role, SecurityIdentifier)
                If (sid.IsWellKnown(WellKnownSidType.AccountAdministratorSid) OrElse sid.IsWellKnown(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinAdministratorsSid)) Then
                    result = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next
        CloseHandle(ph)
        Return result
    End Function

End Module
```

Comment: I applied your revised code. And I was left with one minor error that I was unable to fix. I imported a picture of the error into my post above ^^^

Comment: @Kory Haas - You have to declared the `DllImport` functions as `Shared`. In my example, they were in a `Module` and so implicitly declared as `Shared`.

Comment: @Kory Haas - If this answers your question, do not forget to accept it!